# How can i put line change in a TextBox with a SpeechRecognizer EventArgs variable

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm creating a speech recognizer and i have to put the SpeechRecognizer EventArgs variable but I want what I say to accumulate in a text box and when I stop and start over, it so not be replaced

my code:

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        engine_load();

    }
    private void engine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Multiline = true;
        textBox1.Text = e.Result.Text + Environment.NewLine;
    }

    private void engine_load()
    {


            engine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
            engine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            Grammar g = new DictationGrammar();
            engine.LoadGrammar(g);
            engine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            engine.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(engine_SpeechRecognized);
            Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can declare a global variable `text` to hold the previously entered string.

Please refer to the following code.

```
string text;

private void engine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Multiline = true;
    text += e.Result.Text + Environment.NewLine;
    textBox1.Text = text;
}
```